# Correct element.getElementsByTagName() implementation

Tags: javascript, html, dom

//EDIT My issue was related to something else, I thought the implementation was incorrect but it actually works, thanks for the confirmation.

Looked in jQuery and prototypejs, can't seem to find the way they implement *getElementsByTagName* on a element (not document.getElementsByTagName).

Here's my test html:

```
<div id="something" style="margin: 10px 10px 10px 15px; overflow: auto; position: relative; height: 200px;">
    <div style="float: left; width: 180px; font-size: 10px; margin-bottom: 4px;">
        <label for="label_50">
            <img style="vertical-align: middle; margin-right: 3px;" src="http://web1.wow.com/i/i_ask_sm.gif"/>
            <a style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-decoration: underline;" href="http://myjeeves.ask.com/mysearch/BookmarkIt?v=1.2&t=webpages&url=[URL]&title=[TITLE]" post_link="http://myjeeves.ask.com/mysearch/BookmarkIt?v=1.2&t=webpages&url=[URL]&title=[TITLE]" rel="external" target="_blank">Ask</a>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my current js:

```
document.getElementById("something").getElementsByTagName("a");
```

I'm looking for the correct implementation of this because of course IE doesn't seem to work correctly with it, and I **can't use a framework**.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail how getElementsByTagName is not working for you in IE?

Comment: This *should* work in IE just fine, as long as: (1) you don't have any element in your DOM preceding this HTML with a NAME attribute set to "something"... and you are not trying to find [param] elements.

Comment: @scunliffe: what I was trying to do is: someObject.property = document.getElementById("something").getElementsByTagName("a"); This wasn't working in IE, it wasn't copying the generated array over, so I had to loop through it and added it to a local array, then copied it over, weird stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div id="something" style="margin: 10px 10px 10px 15px; overflow: auto; position: relative; height: 200px;">
    <div style="float: left; width: 180px; font-size: 10px; margin-bottom: 4px;">
        <label for="label_50">
            <img style="vertical-align: middle; margin-right: 3px;" src="http://web1.wow.com/i/i_ask_sm.gif"/>
            <a style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-decoration: underline;" href="http://myjeeves.ask.com/mysearch/BookmarkIt?v=1.2&t=webpages&url=[URL]&title=[TITLE]" post_link="http://myjeeves.ask.com/mysearch/BookmarkIt?v=1.2&t=webpages&url=[URL]&title=[TITLE]" rel="external" target="_blank">Ask</a>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<pre>
<script type="text/javascript">
var lnks = document.getElementById("something").getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var ii = 0; ii < lnks.length; ++ii) {
    document.writeln(lnks[ii].href);
}
</script>
</pre>
```

In IE6, IE7 and IE8RC1 this outputs:

```
http://myjeeves.ask.com/mysearch/BookmarkIt?v=1.2&t=webpages&url=[URL]&title=[TITLE]
```

Does your example not actually demonstrate the problem?

Comment: I just realized the problem is related to something else, will update my question.